# Deprecated Xcode issues

Tags: objective-c, ios7

im getting errors and warnings with the following code:

1. Warning undeclared selector uniqueIdentifier at the first if statement;
2. Error Property uniqueIdentifier not found on object of type UIDevice
3. Error Cast of C pointer type CFStringRef

// Get the users Device Model, Display Name, Unique ID, Token & Version Number

```
UIDevice *dev = [UIDevice currentDevice];
NSString *deviceUuid;
if ([dev respondsToSelector:@selector(uniqueIdentifier)]) // Warning #1
    deviceUuid = dev.uniqueIdentifier; // Error #1
else {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    id uuid = [defaults objectForKey:@"deviceUuid"];
    if (uuid)
        deviceUuid = (NSString *)uuid;
    else {
        CFStringRef cfUuid = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, CFUUIDCreate(NULL));
        deviceUuid = (NSString *)cfUuid; // Error #2
        CFRelease(cfUuid);
        [defaults setObject:deviceUuid forKey:@"deviceUuid"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Unique identifier is depreciated in iOS 7 now... identifierForVendor and advertisingIdentifier are available in ios 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIDevice `uniqueIdentifier` property is deprecated in iOS 5 and above

```
    udid = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    NSLog(@"UDID : %@", udid);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You must create a method with name uniqueIdentifier
2. UIDevice does not have a property called uniqueIdentifier. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now).
3. Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640367/how-to-convert-cfstringref-to-nsstring).