# Convert CFStringRef to NSString

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to retrieve some info from the main bundle:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {    
    CFStringRef bundleVer = CFBundleGetValueForInfoDictionaryKey(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), kCFBundleVersionKey);
    NSString *appVersion = (__bridge NSString *)bundleVer;
}
```

I can get the CFStringRef (in debug I can see the proper value associate to the variable), but when I try to cast it to NSString my appVersion variable has "null" value (previously it was nil).

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using ARC.

EDIT: It seems that I have problem with my project, every NSString object can't be assigned even with a simple static assignment, the value of the test variable is (null)

```
NSString *test = @"";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert CFStringRef to NSString?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640367/how-to-convert-cfstringref-to-nsstring)

Comment: What is the value of your CFStringRef? I copied your code and it totally works on my app.

Comment: Working fine in my app also..

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with misspelling "bundle".

Comment: The value is 34 as it is in my bundle file... after the assignment the appVersion goes from nil to (null)

Answer (score 1):

```
  CFStringRef boundleVer = CFBundleGetValueForInfoDictionaryKey(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), kCFBundleVersionKey);
  NSString *appVersion = (__bridge NSString *)(boundleVer);
```

Its working fien on my side,, it is returning "2"

Answer (score 0):

I would use that code instead of your current one to fetch the same information:

---

```
NSString *_shortVersion = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
```

or

```
NSString *_version = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```

---

*NOTE: I'm not sure which information you need eventually from the bundle.*