# Convert from CFURLRef or CFStringRef to std::string

Tags: c++, macos, stdstring, cfstring, cfurl-encoding

How can I convert a `CFURLRef` to a C++ `std::string`?

I also can convert from the `CFURLRef` to a `CFStringRef` by:

```
CFStringRef CFURLGetString ( CFURLRef anURL );
```

But now I have the same problem. How can I convert the `CFStringRef` to a `std::string`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A CFStringRef [is *toll free bridged*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/640381/981049) to a NSString object, so if you're using Cocoa or Objective C in any way, converting is super simple:

```
NSString *foo = (NSString *)yourOriginalCFStringRef;
std::string *bar = new std::string([foo UTF8String]);
```

More detail [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001677/how-do-i-convert-a-nsstring-into-a-stdstring).

Now, since you didn't tag this question with Cocoa or Objective-C, I'm guessing you don't want to use the Objective-C solution.

In this case, you need to get the C string equivalent from your CFStringRef:

```
const CFIndex kCStringSize = 128; 
char temporaryCString[kCStringSize];
bzero(temporaryCString,kCStringSize);
CFStringGetCString(yourStringRef, temporaryCString, kCStringSize, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
std::string *bar = new std::string(temporaryCString);
```

I didn't do any error checking on this code and you may need to null terminate the string fetched via `CFStringGetCString` (I tried to mitigate that by doing `bzero`).

Answer (score 9):

This function is possibly the most simple solution:

```
const char * CFStringGetCStringPtr ( CFStringRef theString, CFStringEncoding encoding );
```

Of course, there is a ctr for std::string(char*) which gives you this one-liner for the conversion:

```
std::string str(CFStringGetCStringPtr(CFURLGetString(anUrl),kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
```

Comment: While this answer is simple, it bit me recently. I just discovered that in the docs, the comment next to `CFStringGetCStringPtr` says: `/* May return NULL at any time; be prepared for NULL */`. So be careful if you use this.

Answer (score 2):

The safest way of achieving this would be:

```
CFIndex bufferSize = CFStringGetLength(cfString) + 1; // The +1 is for having space for the string to be NUL terminated
char buffer[bufferSize];

// CFStringGetCString is documented to return a false if the buffer is too small 
// (which shouldn't happen in this example) or if the conversion generally fails    
if (CFStringGetCString(cfString, buffer, bufferSize, kCFStringEncodingUTF8))
{
    std::string cppString (buffer);
}
```

The `CFStringGetCString` is not documented to return a NULL like `CFStringGetCStringPtr` can.

Make sure that you are using the correct `CFStringEncoding` type. I think that UTF8 encoding should be safe for most things.

You can check out Apple's documentation about `CFStringGetCString` at https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/1542721-cfstringgetcstring?language=objc

Comment: FYI: `CFStringGetLength(cfString)` returns length for `UTF-16`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation of conversion function

```
std::string stdStringFromCF(CFStringRef s)
{
    if (auto fastCString = CFStringGetCStringPtr(s, kCFStringEncodingUTF8))
    {
        return std::string(fastCString);
    }
    auto utf16length = CFStringGetLength(s);
    auto maxUtf8len = CFStringGetMaximumSizeForEncoding(utf16length, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    std::string converted(maxUtf8len, '\0');

    CFStringGetCString(s, converted.data(), maxUtf8len, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    converted.resize(std::strlen(converted.data()));

    return converted;
}
```

Didn't test that yet.